# How to change default value and update with new value in TextInput in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

How to update value of textinput in react native. I'm making notes taking app in which I get value from asynchoronus storage. And I want to edit that note value which I take as a default value. I want to update value in storage using textinput. My code is below. Please give a proper answer. Thank You.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { FAB,IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import Header from './Header.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default function EditNotes({navigation}) {
    const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState('')
    const [noteDescription, setNoteDescription] = useState('')
    const [noteTitlenew, setNoteTitlenew] = useState('')
    const [noteDescriptionnew, setNoteDescriptionnew] = useState('')

    getValueFunction = () => {
        //function to get the value from AsyncStorage
        AsyncStorage.getItem('onetitle').then(value =>
          //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
          setNoteTitle(value)
        );
        AsyncStorage.getItem('onedesc').then(value =>
          //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
          setNoteDescription(value)
        );
      };

  return (
    <>
    <Header titleText = 'Edit Note' />
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {getValueFunction()}
        <TextInput
           placeholder = "Add Note Title here"
           defaultValue = {noteTitle}
           value = {noteTitlenew}
           onChangeText = {setNoteTitlenew}
           style = {styles.title}
        />
        <TextInput
            placeholder = "Add Note Description"
            defaultValue = {noteDescription}
            value = {noteDescriptionnew}
            onChangeText = {setNoteDescriptionnew}
            multiline={true}
            style={styles.text}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            returnKeyLabel='done'
            blurOnSubmit={true}
        />
        <FAB
        style={styles.fab}
        small
        icon='check'
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingHorizontal:10
  },
  title:{
      fontSize:24,
      marginBottom:16,
      borderWidth:1,
      padding:15
  },
  text: {
      fontSize:16,
      borderWidth:1,
      padding:15
  },
  fab:{
      position:'absolute',
      margin:20,
      right:20,
      bottom:0,
  }
});
```

Comment: "Please give a proper answer" sounds pretty bad here. Please consider editing that out of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use 2 separate states for default and value, instead, you can achieve the desired result by providing a single state for value and default value. Please update your code to the following

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { FAB,IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import Header from './Header.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default function EditNotes({navigation}) {
    const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState('')
    const [noteDescription, setNoteDescription] = useState('')

    getValueFunction = () => {
        //function to get the value from AsyncStorage
        AsyncStorage.getItem('onetitle').then(value =>
          //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
          setNoteTitle(value)
        );
        AsyncStorage.getItem('onedesc').then(value =>
          //AsyncStorage returns a promise so adding a callback to get the value
          setNoteDescription(value)
        );
      };

  return (
    <>
    <Header titleText = 'Edit Note' />
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {getValueFunction()}
        <TextInput
           placeholder = "Add Note Title here"
           defaultValue = {noteTitle}
           value = {noteTitle}
           onChangeText = {setNoteTitle}
           style = {styles.title}
        />
        <TextInput
            placeholder = "Add Note Description"
            defaultValue = {noteDescription}
            value = {noteDescription}
            onChangeText = {setNoteDescription}
            multiline={true}
            style={styles.text}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            returnKeyLabel='done'
            blurOnSubmit={true}
        />
        <FAB
        style={styles.fab}
        small
        icon='check'
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingHorizontal:10
  },
  title:{
      fontSize:24,
      marginBottom:16,
      borderWidth:1,
      padding:15
  },
  text: {
      fontSize:16,
      borderWidth:1,
      padding:15
  },
  fab:{
      position:'absolute',
      margin:20,
      right:20,
      bottom:0,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use react native carefully read the react native documentation.

About your code u don't want to need two state for updated and initial value, and you can pass the default value you in the useState and call it.